# Incomplete statement of commutativity of summation in Concrete Mathematics?

Tags: notation, summation

My [text](http://unina.stidue.net/Complementi%20di%20Analisi%20Matematica/Materiale/Concrete%20Mathematics.pdf) (p. 30, eq. 2.17) states the "commutative law" for sums as

$$\sum\limits_{k\in K}{a_k} = \sum\limits_{p(k)\in K}{a_{p(k)}}$$

where $p$ is a permutation and $K$ is a set of integers.

While [I understand how](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/145754/12400) this rule, as stated, can be applied, I don't understand how this can be a complete statement of commutativity, or suffice for the manipulations made subsequently (in fact, immediately following; second equality of second to last equation on same page) in the text.

Isn't it more complete (and necessary of the law is to be used as it seems to be in subsequent discussion) to say

$$\sum\limits_{k\in K}{a_k} = \sum\limits_{k\in p(K)}{a_{q(k)}}$$

where $K$ is *ordered*, $p(K)$ is $p$ applied to each element of $K$, and $p$ and $q$ are any permutations (including $p=q$ and $p(k)=q(k)=k$)?

---

As stated in the text, saying $p(k)\in K$ is no different from saying $k\in K$ (since $K$ has no order), an failing to distinguish $p$ and $q$ misses the opportunity to independently rearrange summand expression and the summation order (a technique used often in the text).

Comment: Doesn't a subset of the integers have an implicit ordering?

Comment: @ZachGershkoff: It might; I don't know (I always think of sets as unordered unless told otherwise, but I'm *not* an expert); that may be part of the answer and would address the first part of the issue. The bigger part of the question would remain though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s probably better to think of this commutative law as a *renaming* law: it says that as long as the renaming is bijective and is carried out consistently, it doesn’t affect the value of the summation. The consistency is enforced by having $p(k)$ both in the range of summation and in the summand. And the consistency is important. Suppose that $K=\{1,2\}$, $a_k=k$, $p:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z:k\mapsto 3-k$, and $q:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z:k\mapsto k+3$. Then

$$\sum_{p(k)\in K}a_{q(k)}=\sum_{3-k\in K}(k+3)=9\ne3=\sum_{k\in K}k=\sum_{k\in K}a_k\;.$$

Let’s take a look at the specific example that you mention,

$$\sum_{0\le n-k\le n}\big(a+b(n-k)\big)=\sum_{0\le k\le n}(a+bn-bk)\;,$$

to see that this renaming law actually suffices.

Let $K=\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ and $p:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z:k\mapsto n-k$; $p$ is a permutation of the integers, and $p[K]=K$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{0\le n-k\le n}\big(a+b(n-k)\big)&=\sum_{p(k)\in K}\big(a+bp(k)\big)\\
&=\sum_{k\in K}(a+bk)&(\text{commutativity})\\
&=\sum_{p(k)\in p[K]}(a+bk)&(p\text{ is a permutation})\\
&=\sum_{p(k)\in K}(a+bk)&(p[K]=K)\\
&=\sum_{p(k)\in K}\big(a+bn-b(n-k)\big)\\
&=\sum_{p(k)\in K}\big(a+bn-bp(k)\big)\\
&=\sum_{k\in K}(a+bn-bk)&(\text{commutativity})\\
&=\sum_{0\le k\le n}(a+bn-bk)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Nice (and very helpful) answer! I see how this is probably a better (more general) way to think about it. But isn't it about something a bit different. Specifically, $q:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z:k\mapsto k+3$ is not a permutation of $K$ (though it is a renaming). Would  it be right to say then that my reformulation is correct (and needed for the manipulations in the text) if $p$ and $q$ are limited to being permutations; but that the original formulation is sufficient if $p$ is a *renaming*?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Note that the $p$ in the statement of the commutative law in *Concrete Mathematics* is a permutation of *all* the integers, not just of $K$. You need that freedom in order to carry out such manipulations as $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}x^n=x\sum_{k=0}^nx^n$. Even if you limit yourself to permutations of $K$, you don’t need more than the text version, just as I didn’t in the example: the fact that $p[K]=K$ lets you write $\sum_{k\in K}a_k=\sum_{p(k)\in K}a_{p(k)}=\sum_{k\in K}a_{p(k)}$, and $q\circ p^{-1}$ is also a permutation of $K$.

Comment: Ah , I wasn't seeing that I could conclude that $\sum\nolimits_{p(k)\in K}{a_{p(k)}} = \sum\nolimits_{k\in K}{a_{p(k)}}$ (presumably since $\sum\nolimits_{p(k)\in K}{a_{p(k)}} = \sum\nolimits_{p(k)\in p[K]}{a_{p(k)}} = \sum\nolimits_{k\in K}{a_{p(k)}}$) — I mean I *saw* it, but wasn't seeing that it followed from what had been said so far in the text. Is that right? Also, I'm not clear about why $p$ needs to be a permutation of anything beyond $K$.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius: Yes, that’s right. \\ You want to allow permutations that go beyond $k$ so that you can do things like index shifts: $\sum_{k=0}^nkx^{k+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(k-1)x^k$, and the like. The *Concrete Mathematics* rule combines reordering, shifting, and reordering **and** shifting into a single rule.

Comment: Got it: I was thinking only of reorderings.