# How do you understand renaming of summation variables?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

As a part of [a Knuth example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145754), I struggle to understand how you flip the index so easily:

$$\sum_{0 < j < k}(k-j) = \sum_{0 < k-j < k} j.$$

Why doesn't Knuth exchange the summand with the summation variable $k$ in

$$\sum_{j < k < n}(k-j) = \sum_{j < k+j < n} k?$$

OK, the latter is easy to understand: no matter which variable/expression you have between $j$ and $n$, the summand is $j$ less than that. But which picture should I imagine to understand the variable change in the first summation?

Comment: $j_1=k-j,\ j=k-j_1, \sum\limits_{0 < j < k}{k-j} = \sum\limits_{0 < k-j_1 < k} j_1$

Comment: Note that $$\sum_{0 < j < k} (k - j) = (k - 1) + (k - 2) + \cdots + 2 + 1$$ while $$\sum_{0 < k - j < k} j = 1 + 2 + \cdots + (k - 2) + (k - 1)$$  Compare the two sums.

Answer (score 3):

In essence we’re just making a substitution $\ell=k-j$. Of course then $j=k-\ell$, so

$$\sum_{0<j<k}(k-j)=\sum_{0<k-\ell<k}\ell\;.\tag{1}$$

Now rename $\ell$ to $j$, and the righthand side of $(1)$ becomes

$$\sum_{0<k-j<k}j\;.$$